# Xcode 10.3 failing to run on iOS 13 iPhone X - This iPhone X is running iOS 13.0 (17A577), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios13

I updated to iOS 13 on my iPhone X and have Xcode 10.3 and am unable to run my project ton my phone. It gives me a notice of:

> Could not locate device support files

and gives me this error:

> This iPhone X is running iOS 13.0 (17A577), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

I've looked everywhere, but since this release is new, how can I fix this?

Comment: Upgrade to Xcode 11 (at the moment you need Xcode 11 GM 2).

Comment: And this has been [covered many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=This++is+running+which+may+not+be+supported+by+this+version+of+Xcode).

Comment: @rmaddy do you happen to know how much disk space Xcode 11 GM 2 takes up?

Comment: Finder shows the Xcode 11 GM 2 app as 16.15 GB. Plus the download was nearly 8 GB.

Comment: if anyone downloaded xcode 11 , please share the above file which is located in
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade your Xcode to the latest 11.0 in App Store, which contain support for iOS 13.

Answer (score 7):

Your version of Xcode does not have the supporting files for running iOS 13.
The easiest way to do that is to have Xcode 11 installed on your mac (or on someone else's mac) in addition to Xcode 10.3 (it's better to rename one of them)

Go to Applications folder, right click on Xcode 11 icon → Show Package Contents, navigate to folder `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

And copy the folder `13.0`

Go back to Applications, right click on Xcode 10.3 icon → Show Package Contents, navigate to folder `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

Now, paste that folder.

Quit Xcode and run again.
Happy Coding ‍

Comment: This answer worked for me. I am unable to use XCode 11 due to a problem with IPAs created with XCode 11 on Catalina crashing on pre-iOS13 versions.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Developer disk image for iOS 13.0 from here and added support file in Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8).

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip

All other devices support list.

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

Follow These steps.

Unzip downloaded file. Right click on Xcode and click on Show Package Content. Then paste your file on path.

Applications -> Xcode.app -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport Then at last restart your Xcode.

It works for me.